# Generate new rows and fill them in sequentially in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table which currently looks like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 3 |
| 200 | 4 |
| 300 | 1 |

From this, I want a table which has new rows created that count from 1 to the value listed in Column B, so:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 100 | 2 |
| 100 | 3 |
| 200 | 1 |
| 200 | 2 |
| 200 | 3 |
| 200 | 4 |
| 300 | 1 |

Answer (score 3):

You may use `tidyr::uncount` by specifying `.id` argument to get the sequential index.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% uncount(ColumnB, .id = "ColumnB")

#  ColumnA ColumnB
#1     100       1
#2     100       2
#3     100       3
#4     200       1
#5     200       2
#6     200       3
#7     200       4
#8     300       1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ColumnA = c(100L, 200L, 300L), ColumnB = c(3L, 
4L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `rep` + `sequence`

```
with(
    df,
    data.frame(
        ColumnA = rep(ColumnA, ColumnB),
        ColumnB = sequence(ColumnB)
    )
)
```

gives

```
  ColumnA ColumnB
1     100       1
2     100       2
3     100       3
4     200       1
5     200       2
6     200       3
7     200       4
8     300       1
```

## Data

```
df <- structure(list(ColumnA = c(100L, 200L, 300L), ColumnB = c(3L,
4L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```